# Por que não estou conseguindo entrar no else if deste código

Tags: java, acentuação

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Iterator; 
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ControladorVeiculo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList <Veiculo> veiculos = new ArrayList<>();
            while (true){
                System.out.println("Digite 1 para digitar um Veículo ou qualquer outro número para sair");
                Scanner entrada1 = new Scanner (System.in);
                int valorEntrada = entrada1.nextInt();

                if (valorEntrada == 1){
                    System.out.println("Digite PASSEIO para instanciar um carro " +
                             "de passeio ou CAMINHÃO para instanciar um caminhão ");
                    Scanner entrada2 = new Scanner (System.in);
                    String veiculoStr = entrada2.nextLine();
                    if(veiculoStr.equals("PASSEIO")){
                         CarroPasseio passeio = new CarroPasseio();
                        System.out.println("Digite o modelo do seu carro de passeio: ");
                         String modelo = entrada2.nextLine();
                         passeio.setModelo(modelo);
                         System.out.println("Digite a placa do seu carro: ");
                         String placa = entrada2.nextLine();
                         passeio.setPlaca(placa);
                         System.out.println("Digite a capacidade máxima de pessoas que o carro suporta: ");
                         int capacidadeMaxima = entrada2.nextInt();
                         passeio.setCapacidadeMaxima(capacidadeMaxima);
                         System.out.println("Digite a cor do seu carro: ");
                         String cor = entrada2.nextLine();
                         passeio.setCor(cor);
                         System.out.println("Digite o peso que seu carro suporta: ");
                         double pesoTotal = entrada2.nextDouble();
                         passeio.setPeso(pesoTotal);
                         veiculos.add(passeio);
                   }else if(veiculoStr.equals("CAMINHÃO")){
                       Caminhao novo = new Caminhao();
                            System.out.println("Digite o modelo do seu caminhão: ");
                            String modelo2 = entrada2.nextLine();
                            novo.setModelo(modelo2);
                            System.out.println("Digite a placa do seu caminhão: ");
                            String placa2 = entrada2.nextLine();
                            novo.setPlaca(placa2);
                            System.out.println("Digite a capacidade máxima de pessoas que o seu caminhão suporta: ");
                            int capacidadeMaxima2 = entrada2.nextInt();
                            novo.setCapacidadeMaxima(capacidadeMaxima2);
                            System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de carga máxima que seu caminhão suporta: ");
                            double cargaMaxima = entrada2.nextDouble();
                            novo.setCargaMaxima(cargaMaxima);
                            System.out.println("Digite a altura maxima do seu caminhão: ");
                            double alturaMaxima = entrada2.nextDouble();
                            novo.setAlturaMaxima(alturaMaxima);
                            System.out.println("Digite o comprimento do seu caminhão: ");
                            double comprimento = entrada2.nextDouble();
                            novo.setComprimento(comprimento);
                            veiculos.add(novo);
                   }else
                       break;

                }else
                    break;

               }
                   Iterator<Veiculo> it = veiculos.iterator();
                   while(it.hasNext()){
                       Veiculo v = it.next();
                       System.out.println(v.toString());
                       if(v instanceof CarroPasseio ){
                           System.out.println("É um veiculo de Passeio");
                       }
                       if(v instanceof Caminhao){
                           System.out.println("É um caminhão");
                       }


                   }

            }
        }
```

O erro é de execução, quando executo e digito "CAMINHÃO" o programa termina! Como eu faço pra resolver isso? Para ser mais especifico o else if que ele não entra é o que está na linha 36 não sei por que isso está acontecendo... Quando eu tirei o Ã de caminh(ã)o e deixei apenas "CAMINHAO" funcionou, mas por que isso acontece?

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema é encoding de acentos e o seguinte teste confirma. Basta colocar alguns `System.out.println` nos seus `else`s:

```java
            } else {
                System.out.println("Voce digitou " + veiculoStr);
                break;
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Voce digitou " + valorEntrada);
            break;
        }
```

Você verá que o que aparece quando você digita "CAMINHÃO" não é exatamente o que deveria ser. o `Ã` vai ser trocado por alguma outra coisa. Eis o que acontece comigo:

```
Digite 1 para digitar um Veículo ou qualquer outro número para sair
1
Digite PASSEIO para instanciar um carro de passeio ou CAMINHÃO para instanciar um caminhão 
CAMINHÃO
Voce digitou CAMINH�O
```

Ok, e como arrumar isso? Assim:

```java
Scanner entrada2 = new Scanner(System.in, "windows-1252");
```

Ou talvez assim:

```java
Scanner entrada2 = new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
```

Eis o resultado na minha máquina (é o mesmo com qualquer uma das duas formas):

```
Digite 1 para digitar um Veículo ou qualquer outro número para sair
1
Digite PASSEIO para instanciar um carro de passeio ou CAMINHÃO para instanciar um caminhão 
CAMINHÃO
Digite o modelo do seu caminhão:
```

Mais algumas dicas:

1. Você deveria ter postado um pouco das classes `Veiculo`, `CarroPasseio` e `Caminhao`. Felizmente recriá-las com alguns getters e setters não foi difícil.
2. Você só deveria usar um `Scanner` para ler a entrada. Não tem sentido ter dois ou mais.
3. No laço `while` no final, seria mais fácil usar o *enhanced-for* para não precisar lidar com `Iterator`s.
4. A forma de codificação "windows-1252" é horrorosa. Tente se livrar dela se possível. Usar "ISO-8859-1" é um pouco menos pior, mas ainda é ruim.

Comment: Eu acho que você está certo, mas só o AP pode confirmar isso: afinal, esse foi o resultado que você obteve no *seu* ambiente, nada garante que o console do AP também use `windows-1252` (de novo, acho provável que sim). De todo modo, acho estranho, pois o `Scanner` criado com um único argumento *deveria* usar a codificação padrão da plataforma... No mais, concordo com todos os pontos levantados na sua resposta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Testei com ISO-8859-1 e deu certo também. Eu havia verificado isso antes mas tinha dado errado porque eu tinha colocado no `Scanner` errado sem querer e pensei que tinha falhado. Concordo que é super estranho e quando tentei obter o encoding nativo deu que era UTF-8. Então não sei ainda o que fazer para mitigar esse detalhe e detectar o encoding do input de uma forma decente.

Comment: Trabalhar com terminal é sempre complicado... Eu já tive problemas parecidos, só que no Python (PyPy) e não no Java. No fim das contas, era [um bug na implementação...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471585/520779) Pode ser que o Java tenha problemas semelhantes, não sei (não é estranho que na hora de imprimir os acentos na tela ele faz corretamente, mas na hora de ler do teclado não?).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Este de ler errado e escrever certo é o mais bizarro. Isto também é bizarro: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904391/scanner-vs-system-console-write

Answer (score -1):

Porque você está usando caracteres especiais. `~` não é aconselhável usar para verificações,  certamente essa função não reconhece os caracteres especiais. Por exemplo, na linguagem C para colocar acentos tem que por em hex, então certamente é isso. A função não reconhece os acentos... Caso queira entender melhor use breakpoints e dê um debug, com isso você faz uma verificação adequada.